# How to create a container where divs fill it horizontally and vertically (and with margin on 4 sides)?

Tags: html, css

This is the closest I could get:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body,
main {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #413c32;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
}
article[_v-f4d9afa6] {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
article[_v-e514def2] {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  /* margin-bottom: 15px; */
  margin-left: 15px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
article section[_v-e514def2] {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article _v-f4d9afa6="">
    <article class="modal v-transition" _v-e514def2="">
      <section _v-e514def2="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </section>
    </article>
    <article class="modal v-transition" _v-e514def2="">
      <section _v-e514def2="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </article>
</main>
```

[image]

But as you can see the bottom margin is lost. The margin only stays if there's only one panel.

How can I do it so there's always a bottom margin regardless of how many panels I have? (The height of the panels will always sum up to 100%.)

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n08vanje/5/).

Comment: Flexbox or display table.

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude Could you give me an example of that?

Comment: To use flexbox, first you need to remove all styles and then see a flexbox tutorial. To use display table, you need to set `display: table` to parent and then `display: table-cell` to childs, by this mode, all shrinks to fit exactly in your sizes.

Comment: Your fiddle contains the margin on the bottom, but you'll have to scroll. What do you want to achieve? The bottom margin to be visible at all time without scrolling?

Comment: So you're good? Edit: The first fiddle was closer to what you want to achieve, wasn't it? :P

Comment: @chrisv Not really. I need to keep the body with margin 0.

Comment: @alexchenco Is this the kind of result you are after? https://jsfiddle.net/n08vanje/3/

Comment: @Hidden Hobbes Perfect! Could you post this as an answer with a litttle explanation? I'm new to the flex property. I'll accept the answer immediately.

Comment: @alexchenco Cool, just wanted to check. I'll write up an answer to explain what is going on.

Comment: It's because each 'article' has height 50%, so this doesn 't take into account of the margins. But as you can see hidden has provided you the correct answer by using flexbox :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

This is due to the cumulative height of the two child elements (`article[_v-e514def2]`) pushing the height of the parent (`article[_v-f4d9afa6]`) over the desired level. The child elements have `margin`s as well as `height` applied to them which effectively means that that total height they occupy of the parent is **50% + 50% + margins**.

### Resolution

To fix you need to ensure that the total `height` is equal to `50%`. There are a couple of ways to achieve this:

#### Use calc

Using `calc` we can remove `margin-top` from the `height`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body,
main {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #413c32;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
}
article[_v-f4d9afa6] {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
article[_v-e514def2] {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: calc(50% - 15px);
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  /* margin-bottom: 15px; */
  margin-left: 15px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
article section[_v-e514def2] {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article _v-f4d9afa6="">
    <article class="modal v-transition" _v-e514def2="">
      <section _v-e514def2="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </section>
    </article>
    <article class="modal v-transition" _v-e514def2="">
      <section _v-e514def2="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </article>
</main>
```

#### Use flexbox

Using the `flexbox` model will tell the child elements to automatically grow to a suitable `height` to fit the parent:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body,
main {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #413c32;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
}
article[_v-f4d9afa6] {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
article[_v-e514def2] {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  /* margin-bottom: 15px; */
  margin-left: 15px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
article section[_v-e514def2] {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article _v-f4d9afa6="">
    <article class="modal v-transition" _v-e514def2="">
      <section _v-e514def2="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </section>
    </article>
    <article class="modal v-transition" _v-e514def2="">
      <section _v-e514def2="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: @alexchenco At a certain point the height of the child element is forced by the length of the text they contain. If you add `overflow-y: hidden;` or `overflow-y: scroll;` it should allow them to collapse.

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.